# How to sort parallel array from text file

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So I have tried just about everything but just cannot get this to sort, I have to use this sorting algorithm..

So here is the code I have so far, but when ever I run the program it prints out the array in normal order instead of descending order.

```
BufferedReader filein = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Employees.txt"));

    int count = Integer.parseInt(filein.readLine());
    String[] names = new String[count];
    int[] years = new int[count];
    int i;
    int pass;
    int loc;
    int temp;
    String tempNames;
    String passNames;

    System.out.println("My Company Employee Search");
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    System.out.println("");



    for(i=0; i < count-1; i++) {
        names[i] = filein.readLine();
        years[i] = Integer.parseInt(filein.readLine());
    }//populate the arrays from filein

    for(pass = 0; pass<count-1;pass++){
        loc = pass;
        for(i=pass+1; i<count; i++) {
            if(years[i]<years[loc]) {
                loc = i;
            }//end if
        }//end of inner loop



        temp = years[loc];
        years[loc] = years[pass];
        years[pass] = temp;

        names[loc]=names[pass];

        System.out.println(years[loc]+"  "+names[loc]);
    }//end of containg loop
```

And the text file I am loading is:

```
6
Luke
2013
Bob
1980
Ben
2000
Cam
2000
Holly
2001
Joe
1997
```

Comment: Why is name swapping not taking place? name[loc] is loosing it's value every time it's assigned name[pass].

Comment: I shouldn't be saying this. (shows I envy the outcome), but first you say you have to use that particular algorithm, then you mark the one with different algorithm as correct answer. Strange :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    BufferedReader filein = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Employees.txt"));

    int count = Integer.parseInt(filein.readLine());
    String[] names = new String[count];
    int[] years = new int[count];
    int i;
    int pass;
    int loc;
    int temp;
    String tempNames;
    String passNames;

    System.out.println("My Company Employee Search");
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    System.out.println("");



    for (i = 0; i < count ; i++) {
        names[i] = filein.readLine();
        years[i] = Integer.parseInt(filein.readLine());
        //System.out.println("")
    }//populate the arrays from filein


    for(int j=0;j<years.length;j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<j;k++)
        {
            if(years[j]>years[k])
            {
                temp=years[j];
                years[j]=years[k];
                years[k]=temp;

                tempNames=names[j];
                names[j]=names[k];
                names[k]=tempNames;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int j=0;j<years.length;j++)
    {
        System.out.println(" Name = "+names[j]+" And Year = "+years[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Plain Old Java Object (a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object)) and store your file contents in instances of that POJO. As long as you make your POJO implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) you could then use [`Arrays.sort(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object[]%29) to order them how you long.

**Edit**

Then you need to change your second swap.

```
names[loc]=names[pass];
```

Blindly replaces `names[loc]` without saving the previous value.

```
String tempName = names[loc];
names[loc] = names[pass];
names[pass] = tempName;
```

Comment: I have to use this sorting algorithm, I cant use Arrays.sort(Object[])

Answer (score 0):

it's becuase you are printing `name[loc] and year[loc]` after changing their values.

First thing swap contents of name[] properly as I suggested in comment
Second print `name[pass] and year[pass]` as they contain the smaller values, not the one's at `loc`